# Scraping HTML by elements in Python with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I tried to sum up the values that I scraped from the html, however the sum seem very strange.(It obviously lower than the actual value.)

I have looked over other people code and I noticed that they use the `re.findall()` to find the numbers in html.

**My question is that why I could not directly crawl the content element from the html?**
my code is in above and the bottom one is part of code that other people's code different from mine code.

Thank you for your answer in advance!

```
# load in the required packages for reading HTML

from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #parser for HTML
import ssl
import re
# Ignore SSL certificate errors
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE

#open the url
url = 'http://py4e-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_874984.html'
html = urlopen(url, context = ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

# Retrive the information form url
spans = soup('span')
sum = 0
for span in spans:
    x = span.contents[0]
    for n in x:
        sum = sum + int(n)
print(sum)
```

```
sum=0
# Retrieve all of the anchor tags
tags = soup('span')
for tag in tags:
    # Look at the parts of a tag
    y=str(tag)
    x= re.findall("[0-9]+",y)
    for i in x:
        i=int(i)
        sum=sum+i
print(sum)
```

Comment: Are you trying to sum the number of comments?

Comment: I have tried, but I would like to get myself more familar with nested for-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this should get you there:

```
counter = 0
for comment in soup.select('span.comments'):
    counter+=int(comment.text)
print(counter)
```

or even shorter:

```
comments = [int(comment.text) for comment in soup.select('span.comments')]
print(sum(comments))
```

Output, in both cases:

```
2266
```

Comment: @JamesHuang Good to hear! If we're done, don't forget to accept the answer, please.

Comment: Can I ask you one more question about 'span.comments'

Comment: @JamesHuang Sure.